# NGINX: redirect requests from installed nginx to nginx in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two nginx reverse proxy on the same machine:

1. Installed into Ubuntu (takes 80 and 443 ports)
2. nginx in docker container (takes 445 port and mapped to 443)

The installed nginx should redirect particular domain requests to nginx in docker.

Installed nginx config:

```
upstream target {
    server 127.0.0.1:8891 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream target_green {
    server 127.0.0.1:445 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
     set $rootfolder "/var/www/root/";
     set $link "target.domain.example";

     listen 443;
     server_name target.domain.example;
     charset utf-8;
     client_max_body_size 1G;

     add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private_key.key;
     ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
     ssl_session_timeout 6m;

     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
     ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;


     access_log /var/www/app/logs/access.log;
     error_log /var/www/app/logs/error.log;
     gzip on;


     location / {

          proxy_connect_timeout 600;

          proxy_send_timeout 600;

          proxy_read_timeout 600;
          proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_pass http://target;
 
     }

     location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://target;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

     location /static {
          gzip_vary on;
          gzip on;
          gzip_min_length 1100;
          gzip_buffers 16 8k;
          gzip_comp_level 3;
          gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/x-javascript text/css;
          root    /var/www/root/static/;
     }


      location /media {
          gzip_vary on;
          gzip on;
          gzip_min_length 1100;
          gzip_buffers 16 8k;
          gzip_comp_level 3;
          gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/x-javascript text/css;
          root    /var/www/root/media/;
     }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name "target-green.domain.example";

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 1G;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private_key.key;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 6m;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;


    access_log /var/www/app/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/app/logs/error.log;
    gzip on;

  location / {
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;

    proxy_send_timeout 600;

    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass https://target_green;
  }
}
```

nginx-in-docker config:

```
server {
  set $rootfolder "/var/www/app/";
  set $app "http://app:8891";
  set $ws "http:/app-ws:10000";

  listen 443 ssl;

  # Docker DNS
  resolver 127.0.0.11;

  server_name "target-green.domain.example";
  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 1G;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate_key;
  ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 6m;

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl_dhparam;

  access_log /var/www/app/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/app/logs/error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_connect_timeout 159s;
    proxy_send_timeout   600;
    proxy_read_timeout   600;

    proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass $app;
  }

  location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass $ws;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    proxy_redirect    off;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /static {
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    root $rootfolder/frontend/;
  }

  location /media {
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    root $rootfolder/;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, in the browser, I see `target-green.domain.example redirected you too many times.`

Answer (score 0):

In your localhost reverse proxy, you are routing traffic to port 8891 and 445

##################

```
upstream target {
    server 127.0.0.1:8891 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream target_green {
    server 127.0.0.1:445 fail_timeout=0;
}
```

##################

On the docker environment reverse proxy you are listening on port 443.

This may be a problem.

Also, make sure that the docker network is in bridged mode, so it will take traffic from localhost.